# Ubuntu 12.04 - Eclipse looking for different libswt-gtk

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, swt

I'm trying to run a Java application that uses the SWT library in Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 12.04 (x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I'm receiving this error:

**Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/saeed/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4427.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-gtk-4427 in java.library.path
    no swt-gtk in java.library.path
    /home/saeed/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4427.so: /home/saeed/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-4427.so: ELF file data encoding not little-endian (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)
    Can't load library: /home/saeed/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so**

How can I resolve the above problem????

However my problem is that Eclipse is searching for "libswt-gtk-4427.so". I have "libswt-gtk-3836". How do I get the SWT library that Eclipse wants or change the one it's searching for?

Answer (score 0):

it works for me :

```
 echo "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni" >> /etc/eclipse.ini
```